# PHP docker and using MySQL PDO

Tags: php, docker

When creating a LEMP stack using PHP-FPM I can't seem to load the PDO dirver it keeps defaulting to the sqlite driver.

Docker compose:

```
version: "3.5"
services:

redis:
  image: redis:alpine
  container_name: errors-redis

mysql:
  image: mysql:8.0
  container_name: errors-mysql
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
    - .:/application
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=errors
    - MYSQL_USER=test
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
  ports:
    - "9011:3306"

webserver:
  image: nginx:latest
  container_name: errors-nginx
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./dev/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  ports:
   - "9010:80"

php-fpm:
  image: php:fpm
  container_name: errors-php-fpm
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
    - .:/application
    - ./dev/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Docker file:

```
FROM phpdockerio/php72-fpm:latest
WORKDIR "/application"

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install  php-memcached php7.2-mysql php-redis php-xdebug \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

PHP ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 108M
```

Now when I check phpinfo()

```
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers sqlite
```

I've not installed sqlite at any point so I'm not sure how it's gotten it. How do I change it to use MySQL instead of sqlite?

Comment: You building image from phpdockerio/php72-fpm:latest and probably in it or its parent image sqlite is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the PDO bits to your install as well...

```
apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install php-memcached php-redis php-xdebug mysqli pdo pdo_mysql \
```

Specifically the last 3.  You can probably miss out the php7.2-mysql as this should be covered with the mysqli option.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work, I can still only see sqlite under the PDO drivers

Comment: I have done a fresh test and it has worked fine, I guess the old config is some how holding state

Comment: I'm never quite sure if you have to re-create the image when changing these settings - haven't done it for a while.

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please consider marking it as answered.